# Is women hair cutting prohibited in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, muslim-practices, hair

I have searched but didn't get any exact answer that, Are women allowed to cut hairs  in Islam? Only cutting of hairs from bottom is prohibited? Or to make hairs like boy cut is prohibited?

Answer (score 1):

Shaykh Ibn ‘Uthaymeen (may Allah have mercy on him) said:

For a woman to cut her hair was regarded as makrooh (disliked) by some scholars, and some scholars said it is haraam (forbidden), and some scholars said it is permissible.